# PF_RING ubuntu installation

Tags: ubuntu, networking, drivers, pf-ring

I am trying to install pf_ring on ubuntu virtual machine , I tried it many many times but every time I fail :( .
so, I am using the tutorial : 
http://www.ntop.org/pf_ring/installation-guide-for-pf_ring/

in this tutorial the driver of `eth0` is `e1000e` , on my computer it's `e1000`.
the first error is in libpcap folder. when I am trying to run 'make' on that folder it's writing `no targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.` . I tried to run `./configure` but it's not helping . I skipped this part of installation.

the second error is when I am trying to install the pf_ring driver.
I am going to `~/PF_RING/drivers/DNA/e1000-8.0.35-DNA/src` folder and running `make` and receiving this : `this driver is not supported on kernel versions older than 2.4.0. Stop.`

maybe someone know what is the problem and how I can install PF_RING ? or maybe someone already have a virtual machine that contains that module and he/she can share it with me ? or maybe someone know a better and newer tutorial (the tutorial in the link is from 2010 ) ?

Thank You !

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have all the required dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential bison flex linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Download the pf_ring tarball with wget, curl or your browser
    https://sourceforge.net/projects/ntop/files/PF_RING/

I would recommend escalating to root for the next few commands

```
tar xf PF_RING-6.4.1.tar.gz
cd PF_RING-6.4.1
make
cd kernel
make install
cd ../userland/lib
make install
modprobe pf_ring
```

That's it.  To check everything worked type

```
modinfo pf_ring
```

Comment: [Installation guide](https://www.ntop.org/guides/pf_ring/get_started/git_installation.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is tutorial under /userland you can use to change your e1000 driver to e1000e. it is fairly hard to do that but it is not impossible.

Your second error

`driver is not supported on kernel versions older than 2.4.0. Stop.`

may be resolved by upgrading your kernel to 4.x. these two solution works for me.

if the errors is still remaining, open an issue on https://github.com/ntop/PF_RING/issues and ask your questions from pf_ring developers.